# My ubuntu randomly clicks on the screen and move text around when I have a text editor open

Tags: 15.10, input

Recently I've noticed my mouse sometimes randomly clicks on buttons even though i didn't click at all. And blocks of text move around my IDE when I leave cursor motionless on the ide. 
Side effects includes:

1. random mouse clicks(left or right).
2. on chrome, randomly sometimes the site is taken to the last page(back).
3. on text editor random blocks of code are pasted as I move the cursor.

Not sure if this is a bug with ubuntu 15 or one of these packages that i recently installed.

- gengetopt
- x11
- screenkey
- slop
- recordmydesktop

Help!! The mouse isn't broken i have installation of windows which I've already tested that this isn't occuring on, neither is keyboard.

---

Edit: I highly doubt that its hardware / model related, as my windows OS works fine without these weird behaviors. and when I say random pasting and going back, no input is logged by `screenkey`, and my mouse isn't twitching (its under my control). I'm not sure how else is input being taken, so I'm pretty sure that the issue occured in one of those Software or the recent Ubuntu 15.10 upgrade, where reading input has a defect.

But... Desktop, assembled, win10 + ubuntu15.10 dual boot.

I use a wired kinesis advantage keyboard, (I've resetted this so custom macro is not the issue), and logitech gaming mouse mx 518.

Comment: Do you have a touchscreen?

Comment: I have no answer, but want to ask when you say mouse, it's actual physical mouse and not touch pad mouse on laptop. My touch pad many times misinterprets the signal or mouse suddenly jumps to location where I am not expecting it.

Comment: What is the type of your computer: desktop, laptop, or tablet? And which model?

Comment: Can you please see if this happens in a live session ?

Comment: If the PC has Bluetooth and WiFi interfaces, turn them off. Who knows...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and respond to the many questions the community has asked you if you intend to actually receive answer. Is your mouse wired or wireless? If wireless are the batteries fresh?

Comment: I have a PS2 keyboard, which on any Linux system I tried would go haywire after a while. Under windows it runs perfectly fine, but for some reason Linux has problems with PS2. What connection does your mouse use?

Comment: @user3005629 whats live session?

Comment: A live session is when an Operative system is booted from an external media with the purpose of trying it out. I want to check if a Live session that is the unmodified system, still presents the problem.